# select non tagged text using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Using xpath I was able to get all text of top level node using `.text` attribute. However, what I really want is the dollars amount and cents amount.
Is there anything I can pinpoint those elements using xpath ?
From my research, Seleninum did not recognize `/text()` suffix with `find_element_by_xpath`

```
<span id='price'>
    <sup>$</sup>4

    <sup>
        <span class="priceDecimalMark">.</span>99

        <span class="priceFlag">
                    *
                    </span>
    </sup>
</span>
```

Comment: Once you have the complete text, use the `split()` method.

For example, if `a = u'$4 .99 *'` then `a.split()` would give you `[u'$4', u'.99', u'*']`, thus now you have dollars, cents seperately.

Comment: Did this work for you?